# Need information about Neo4j File System

Tags: neo4j

You all. I require to know more about the store file of Neo4j. I was wondering if someone answers my questions. 
The following list shows my questions:
1. Do all nodes store in one store file? 
2. Is there another store file to keep or save labels? 
3. Can I read each record from the store files, created by Neo4j, by using the ordinary functions?

Answer (score 2):

This could be helpful for you

http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals

Answer (score 1):

Graph Databases by O'Reilly is free and is a great response for understanding the internals of Neo4j.  They've even come out recently with a second edition:

http://graphdatabases.com/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can explore Neo4j source code.

Store - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/store

For example, if look into [NodeStore](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/store/NodeStore.java) we can find following:

- Nodes are stored in separate file
- Each record use 15 bytes
- Getting node record by id is just: calculate offset and read 15 bytes
- Node record is divided in several parts:

  - [byte] isInUse - can we use this record to store node? (when nodes are deleted, no actual data is deleted, they just mark record as not in use and make it available for future writes)
  - [int] nextRel - pointer to next relationship (stored in separate file)
  - [int] nextProp - point to next property (stored in separate file)
  - [int + byte] some label stuff
  - [byte] "extra"

And so on.

From my experience there are very few resources about Neo4j internals. Most of them are quite outdated.
That why, from my point of view - exploring source code is best view to really get into "how it works".